# Unable to find Build Tools revision 25.0.0 rc1 in build.gradle

Tags: android, design-patterns

This is build.gradle file

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25 rc1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.supportv13.sampleime"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Whenever sync gradle project we are showing a dialog with following text
"**All packages are not available for download!  The following packages are not available:
- Package id build-tools;25.0.0-rc1**"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use an older version of gradle build. 23.0.3 works just fine for me.

Comment: But i want to use some components from API 25 so we have to use   buildToolsVersion "25 rc1".

Comment: Then you might want to do not 25 rc1 but 25.0.1

Answer (score 0):

According to the Android Developer Documentation [website](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html) , the latest available build tool release is Build Tools, *Revision 25.0.1 (November 2016)*. So you should change "25 rc1" to "25.0.1" in your build.gradle file.